How to inspect HTTPS packets on my network?
I'd like to be able to inspect HTTPS traffic on my personal LAN to see what some closed source applications may be sending back to home base.
I've heard that one viable way is to "man in the middle" yourself into these HTTPS transactions. You add a new root signing CA to your system, then proxy your traffic, which uses your new root CA to establish TLS, and from there you can read, and carry out network requests as they come in.
Is this a viable way to sniff encrypted HTTPS traffic as raw unencrypted data? How would I go about doing this?

Wireshark can inspect HTTPS traffic. You will have to break the security of the connection in order to do so. No, there is no way to decrypt encrypted HTTP traffic without the certificate. The raw HTTPS data is encrypted not encrypted.

@Ramhound "encrypted not encrypted" what does this mean?

yes, this is definitely viable, and lots of big enterprises do exactly what you suggest. the simplest approach is to use an enterprise-grade router that supports HTTPS inspection and sends logs to a syslog server, but alternately you can set up a proxy server on your network that performs the inspection. Note that this is non-trivial end-to-end, so may not be worth it if your motivation is idle curiosity.

@tuskiomi - It was a typo. You are asking if you can view the raw HTTPS unencrypted, you can’t because it’s encrypted, until the certificate is used to decrypt it. HTTPS is designed so that it can’t be inspected unless you perform that man in the middle attack and use your own certificate in order to do the inspection.

@FrankThomas Thank you, this is off topic, but is this something that you think ubiquiti may support?

I'm sure that Ubiquity has products in their many lines that would perform that function.

I’m voting to close this question because There's an answer in the comments that solved my issue lol.

That is not how this site works. Please help the community and others who have this question out by sharing the solution to your problem as an answer down below.
